# Sorting and getting higest values codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a cloumn like token_number in table the values inserted in this row are like

```html
token_number

1
2
3
15
4
5
6
14
7
8
18
10
11
9
etc..
```

I sort these values
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,18

I want to get the value 11 from this sorted array
ie the highest number with common difference 1

How to get 11 from this array?

Comment: One way would be to loop it and check for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is sorted, you can start from the bottom e loop it backwards:

```
$arr = // sorted array;
$max = null;
for( $i = count($arr) - 1 ; $i > 0 ; $i++ ){
   if($arr[$i] - 1  == $arr[$i-1]){
      $max = $arr[$i-1];
      break;
   }
}
if($max !== null){
   echo "founded: " . $max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find highest number with command difference as follow.

```
$arr= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,18);
$highestNo = null;

 for($i=0 ;$i <= count($arr) - 1 ;  $i++ ){

     $diff = $arr[$i+1]   - $arr[$i]; //check difference of current and next number

     if($diff != 1){

           $highestNo = $arr[$i];

            break;
      }
}
echo "Highest number with comman difference is: " . $highestNo;
```